# Pass longitude and Latitude with Intent to another class

Tags: android

I am trying to pass the latitude and Longitude from the onLocationChanged in the  MainActivity to another package`com.route.provider` class`DataPrivider` but I am getting this error how can I do that? and how can I receive them in the DataProvider?

```
        double pLong = location.getLongitude();
        double pLat = location.getLatitude();

        LatLng fromPostion = new LatLng(pLat,pLong );

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putParcelable("longLat_dataPrivider", fromPostion);
```

> The method putParcelable(String, Parcelable) in the type Bundle is not applicable for the arguments (String, LatLng)

Comment: That's because LatLng is not Parcelable, put both values directly as it is suggested in two answers present

Comment: That is strange, the documentation says that `LanLng` implements Parcelable: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html

Comment: I just tested this, and it worked just fine for me with `putParcelable()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the problem is not with your code, but possibly with imports or your project setup.

I got this working in Android Studio by passing the the `LatLng` Object as Parcelable in an `Intent` between two Activities.

In my build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:12.0.0'
}
```

In both Activities, use the following import:

```
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
```

Here is the test code that worked for me:

MainActivity.java:

```
double pLong = -121.345678;
double pLat = 37.123456;

LatLng fromPostion = new LatLng(pLat, pLong);

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("longLat_dataPrivider", fromPostion);

Intent i = new Intent(this, MapActivity.class);
i.putExtras(args);
startActivity(i);
```

MapActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity2);

    Intent i = getIntent();

    LatLng ll = i.getParcelableExtra("longLat_dataPrivider");

    Log.d("Location", "location: " + ll.latitude + " " + ll.longitude);

}
```

Comment: in the receiving activity, value of l1 is always null. any help?

Comment: Thanks! I had auto-imported com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng which doesn't implement parcelable. Lesson learned.

Answer (score 2):

`LatLng` cannot be passed like that (sadly).

**EDIT: Daniel Nugent exposed and proved that indeed `LatLng` IS Parcelable. Therefor, it's solution is better than mine I must admit** And I just learn something too.

I would suggest to save lat/lng values separately:

```
intent.putExtra("latitude", latLng.latitude);
intent.putExtra("longitude", latLng.longitude);
```

Then retrieve them like so:

```
final double latitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude");
final double longitude = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude");
final LatLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

Comment: It actually is Parcelable, I just tested it and the OP's code should work.  http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng.html

Comment: Why am I geting these errors in the DataProvider class first; `The method getIntent() is undefined for the type DataProvider`? second; `LatLng cannot be resolved `?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the values directly into intent.

```
intent.putExtra(KEY, VALUE)
```

otherwise try using

```
args.putDouble(LON_KEY, pLong)
args.putDouble(LAT_KEY, pLat)
```