# Google maps API launching error

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, build.gradle

I just followed the instruction from https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup
also included the api key in my androidmanifest file but I am getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzabs;
```

Tried the solutions i found here but didn't work for me. He is my manifest ang gradle file:
Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    aaptOptions {
        ignoreAssetsPattern "!values-b+sr+Latn"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.user.appsightseeing"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile files('libs/YouTubeAndroidPlayerApi.jar')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Androidmanifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.user.appsightseeing">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splashscreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivityp"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivitymo">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivitymu" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailActivityth" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailActivityf"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_detail_activityf"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <!--
             The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
             (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
             Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
             You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
             sign the APK for publishing.
             You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyACKJJ0D-BSWLYEujMz9ybjztDK-1NKIdk" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

So what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same version of all libraries from Google Play Services.

Change `9.0.0` to `10.2.6` for analytics:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.6'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.6'
```

Comment: I am trying it now. Thank you for the reply @DanielNugent. One more question.. Can you give me any hint how to get started now with google maps. I have a navigation drawer whose components are fragment with listvies in it. Onclick details of the item open. I want in this activity with a button click want to open the location on the map..

Comment: It worked thank you @DanielNugent . Also if you can check my other comment.

Comment: @SindiB Take a look here for an example of an Activity that gets the user's current location: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow   As for the ListView, if you have the location, send it as a LatLng extra in the intent used to open the Google Map activity: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30106507/pass-longitude-and-latitude-with-intent-to-another-class

Comment: Thankss I'll check that now @DanielNugent

Comment: do i have to create all the classes appart the answer you provided in the firs link, like LocationRequest, LocationServices and methods ...?

Comment: can you please check my latest question. @DanielNugent MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION cannot be resolved ..